# How to get the count value of zero with a same table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, count, union

**This is the sentence MySql**

```
select if(b.opcionselec='Y','Yes','No') as opt, count(b.idPregunta) as val
from respuestabuleanas as b where b.idPregunta='1' group by (b.opcionselec);
```

**Result  to query**

```
 opt           val
 No             1
```

**What I want to get**

```
 opt           val
 No             1
 Yes            0
```

**Is there any way to achieve it?**

Answer (score 0):

```
select if(b.opcionselec='Y','Yes','No') as opt, count(b.idPregunta) as val
from respuestabuleanas as b 

LEFT JOIN respuestabuleanas as b1 ON b1.idPregunta='1' group by (b.opcionselec);
```

Comment: But This statement returns the result same as above. Only a value is stored in the table the other must be assigned a zero but i not know how?

Comment: I tried this `select opt, count(b.idPregunta) as val
from (Select 'Yes' as opt union select'No')as dbl, respuestabuleanas as b LEFT JOIN respuestabuleanas as b1 on b1.idPregunta='1' group by (opt);` but the value the Yes must be 0 and return 1 on both

Answer (score 0):

```
select if(b.opcionselec='Y','Yes','No') as opt, count(b.idPregunta) as val = 
      CASE opt
         WHEN 'YES' THEN '0'
       END,
from respuestabuleanas as b 

LEFT JOIN respuestabuleanas as b1 ON b1.idPregunta='1' group by (b.opcionselec);
```